# How to configure proxy settings in JS Test café

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, proxy, testcafe

I have been working with Python Selenium, and the following proxy settings and browser options were set as shown below.

```
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxyAutoconfigUrl = "http://wpad/wpad.dat"
ff_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "123.123.123.123")
```

Currently, I automating the same page, and I am unaware of how to specify the above configurations in JS Testcafe.

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed. Please assist.

I made to following discoveries (Testcafe docs), below is the content of package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "DEMO": "testcafe firefox pageObjModel/tests/*.js",
    "proxy": "http://wpad/wpad.dat",
    "proxyBypass": "123.123.123.123"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-xlsx": "^0.21.0",
    "testcafe": "^1.18.1",
    "testcafe-blink-diff": "^0.4.11"
  }
}
```

This does not work. Now I just need help in knowing where exactly I must paste these lines in package.json

```
"proxy": "http://wpad/wpad.dat",
"proxyBypass": "123.123.123.123"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify proxy settings as TestCafe arguments:

```js
"scripts": {
    "DEMO": "testcafe firefox pageObjModel/tests/*.js --proxy http://wpad/wpad.dat --proxy-bypass 123.123.123.123"
  },
```